# "How to apply Red to compile-time optimization of this Lisp code?"

Tags: lisp, compiler-optimization, red

This is a pattern of optimization in Lisp code that I want to achieve in Red:

```
(defmacro compute-at-compile (x)
  `(+ ,(* pi 2) ,x))

(macroexpand '(compute-at-compile 1))
; => (+ 6.283185307179586 1)
```

How do I express this in Red?  (I realize it may not be possible in today's implementation, I'm wondering about how one would express the code at the language level to get such an optimization.  Would it require special markup in the source, or would it be automatic like Lisp?)

Comment: Common Lisp is a dialect of Lisp as well.  The way the macro is expressed or what dialect is used seems to me, to be irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that the dialect in use is irrelevant for your specific question (except that Scheme macros are different, heh), but, fewer people object to CL code being tagged as "Lisp" than Clojure (or Scheme or Arc), just judging by the number of Clojure/Scheme posts on SO where the OP tagged with [tag:lisp] only to have it be untagged by (mainly) CL posters. This is why I converted your code to CL rather than, say, Scheme (which is my primary language, and at which I'm much more adept than CL).

Comment: In any case, Common Lisp, Scheme, Clojure, and Arc are vastly different from each other (in the same way that C++, Perl, Java, JS, and PHP are vastly different, despite those languages having a C-style syntax (`for (...; ...; ...)`, curly-braces for blocks, etc.)), and it's probably best to label your code's language correctly. In particular, I would generally avoid labelling Scheme, Clojure, or Arc code as "Lisp".

Comment: Being more specific is a good idea.  I kept it generically Lisp since the macros in each Lisp are very similar(not the same, but about like the difference of a for loop in the various c-inspired languages), anyway, point taken... I will be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to extend my answer to maybe cover another idea that may help you find what you are looking for.

**Red/System**

From my understanding, the Red/System `#define` directive can help with optimization (in reducing function calls).  Here is a similar example in Red/System.  Within Red, it would require using within `#system` or `#system-global`directive.

```
#define COMPUTE(x) (3.13159 * 2.0 + x)

b: COMPUTE(1.0)
print b
```

Processing the macro should result in:

```
b: (3.13159 * 2.0 + 1.0)
print b
```

and results

```
7.26318
```

Math between types isn't defined yet, so you'll run into issues multiplying/adding `float!` and `integer!` (hence the above use of float!)

**Red/Rebol**

You can also take a look at `compose` as a higher level way to optimize your code writing.  I am unsure of the effect in terms of optimizing speed.  What compose does is take a block and evaluate whatever is in parenthesis and not evaluate other elements in the block.

See the Rebol2 help definition for `compose`

```
>> help compose
USAGE:
    COMPOSE value /deep /only    

DESCRIPTION:
     Evaluates a block of expressions, only evaluating parens, and returns a block.
     COMPOSE is a native value.    

ARGUMENTS:
     value -- Block to compose (Type: any)    

REFINEMENTS:
     /deep -- Compose nested blocks
     /only -- Inserts a block value as a block
```

This may be what you're looking for in terms of building expressions

```
red>> x: 1
== 1
red>> compose [3 + 2 + (x)]
== [3 + 2 + 1]
```

An example from the Rebol2 documentation:

```
>> probe compose [time: (now/time) date: (now/date)]
[time: 12:48:53 date: 5-Mar-2014]
== [time: 12:48:53 date: 5-Mar-2014]
```

Comment: Do you also have a Rebol example by any chance?  Thanks for the Red answer.

Comment: Red/System is a C-like language.  I am not the expert on this but after a little reading, I decided to suggest `compose`  because it may be more what you are looking for to reduce repetition in code writing.